# EnableQueryAttribute with PageSize messes up pre-sorted list

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

When I set the `[EnableQuery]` attribute on a `ApiController` method in `WebAPI 2.2` it seems to break the ordering of response.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Project>))]
[Route("api/user/{userId}/project")]
[EnableQuery(PageSize = 100)]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetForUser(string userId)
{
    // This gets all projects for the user, and sorts by the last access date
    IEnumerable<Project> projects = await this.projectOperations.GetProjectsForUser(userId);

    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, projects);
}
```

I'm calling it without any OData query parameters, and the resulting project list is **89** items, so in my mind it should not process the array at all.

I've verified that it is in fact the `EnableQueryAttribute` that does this by creating a new class deriving from `EnableQueryAttribute`:

```
public class TestEnableQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        // Here the response content is 
        // ObjectContent<IEnumerable<Project>>

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);

        // Afterwards the response content is 
        // ObjectContent<System.Web.Http.OData.Query.TruncatedCollection<Project>>
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that it seems to sort it by the `Id` property of the `Project` class. Is this some kind of undocumented convention?

Anyone know how to stop it from messing with my sorting?
I want to have paging, but unless i actually specify a `$orderby` query parameter it shouldn't do any ordering on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Web API sorts on the primary key (usually ID) if no sort options are given, so that the order of the results are stable for pagination.

You can override this with an attribute to sort as per your returned results - tested with `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` 5.6.0.

```
[EnableQuery(EnsureStableOrdering = false)]
```

In earlier versions you might need to invoke `ODataQueryOptions` yourself - see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options.